# How to make bootstrap carousel image responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to keep the same ratio of the images. The problem is it streches when the browser is wide.
and squezes when it's reduced.

I have checked all SO question here but most of them did not help me.

Here is the **markup:**

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/female/IMG_5053-2.jpg" 
           data-src="images/female/IMG_5053-2.jpg" alt="First slide">
```

---

and here is the **CSS**

```
.carousel .item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I tried to make a jsfiddle but I couldnt here is the link to the page http://maanastore.com/home.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the following CSS rules from respective files:

In home.php file

```
.carousel .item>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

in carousel.css

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Also, add `margin-top: 51px;` to `.carousel` class in carousel.css file and remove `height:500px` from the same class, because you have fixed navbar.

Comment: making postion absolute,and the carousel gone from the page

Comment: add `position:relative` to the parent element.

Answer (score 7):

I found it best to remove the following.

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

and in .carousel remove:

```
height: 500px;
```

and in 
.carousel .item remove

```
 height: 500px;
```

for me this made the image work the way I wanted it to but be sure to insert an image in your html first or else I think it will just collapse into nothingness if you are working locally.

**edit:** Another user suggested I add this
*Please Note that if the image shows grey bars on either side or even on one side, I'd recommend keeping*

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what i ended up doing was adding a div inside then have the image background of the div as responsive

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="img1">
        </div>
<!--<img class=" imgCstm " src="images/home/bng_00.jpg" alt="First slide">-->
    </div> 
</div> 


<style>
  .carousel-inner { 
     height: 100vh;
     <! --  custom hight -->
  }

  .carousel-item  { 
     height: 100%;
  }

  .img1 {
     background-image: url('../images/home/bng_00.jpg');
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed !important;
     background-size: cover !important;   
     background-position: center !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a typical use of *margin*, to improve your result centering your image.

```
.carousel-inner > .carousel-item > img {
margin: 0; //If you have images of very different sizes.    
max-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have been working on a project of such
this might help someone in need of a slider which is responsive with the browser.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:300,400,600,700|Open+Sans:400,400i,700");
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color:black;
}

slider{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
 
 slider > *{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: slide 8s infinite;
 }

 slide:nth-child(1){
  left:0%;
  animation-delay: -10s;
  background-image: url(../images/slider7.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }

 slide:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: -12s;
  background-image: url(../images/slider2.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }


 slide:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: -14s;
  background-image: url(../images/slider6.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }
  slide:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: -16s;
  background-image: url(../images/slider0.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 }


slide p{
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin:10%;
  color:#fff;
}
slide h1{
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color:#fff;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {left:100%; width:100%;}
  5% {left:0%;}
  25% {left:0%;}
  30% {left: -100%; width: 100%;}
  30.0001%{left: -100%; width:0%;}
  100%{left: 100%; width: 0%}

}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <slider>
   <slide></slide>
      <slide><h1>Slide Text one</h1></slide>
      <slide><h1>Slide Text Two</h1></slide>
       <slide><h1>Slide Text Three</h1></slide>
  </slider> 
 </section>
```

This link can also give you more insights [Making Images Responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390931/how-to-make-bootstrap-4-carousel-images-responsive)

Answer (score -1):

I made these adjustment to `bootstrap.css` at lines 5835 - 5847:

```
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  /* Removed height here */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Worked like a champ!