# Bootstrap Carousel: images not behaving responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly, I am aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178012/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-image-responsive) however trying the prescribed solution doesn't seem to work for me. My image appears to no extend in proportion to the viewport of the slider.

I included a screenshot below...
The grey portion in the slide is the default background; Apparently my image is being nudged to the top, but not expanded the full height, which is 500px.

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
     <!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="item active">
     <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" height:"500px" src="/img/4a_slider_w992.png" data-src="/img/4a_slider_w992.png" alt="First slide">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- repeated -->
     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

And this is my css...

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
 .carousel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3f2416;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top:-50px !important;
  }

/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
 z-index: 10;
 top: 50px;
 }

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
 height: 500px; //needed
 background-color: #777;
 width:100%;
 }
```

Of course this is the CSS which the post I referred to said to comment out...

```
// .carousel-inner > .item > img { /*<== as per stackOverFlow*/
//   top: 0;
//   left: 0;
//   min-width: 100%;
//   height: 500px;
// }
```

Comment: and what is your desired behavior?

Comment: I'd like the image to span the height of the container without being distorted...as in the screenshot it's not filling the viewport of the slider...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of the image to cover its parent and letting it scale proportionally by removing the `max-width`

```
.carousel-inner>.item>img, 
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/oLqg68da/2/)**

Comment: Thanks so much for answering! This gets the image to cover the slide but there is no responsiveness...

Comment: Can you explain what kind of responsiveness are you looking for? How about [this changes](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/oLqg68da/4/)? The image now fills the container width in larger screens.

Comment: Essentially this http://maanastore.com/home.php
As you shrink the browser the image scales down to match the view port...