# Bootstrap, images inside carousel caption are not responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created carousel with three slides, by using Bootstrap 3.

In `carousel-inner` where `item` is located i have added image tags. They work well, because they are images for slides and they rresize themselves by screen size.

Inside `item` there is `carousel-caption` I have added `h1` tag with `image` tag inside of it. This image is not resizing it keeps itself always big.

I am missing something??

My code:

```
<!-- Carousel -->
            <div id="carousel-main" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-main" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>


                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img1">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>
                                <img src="images/logo_medium.png">
                            </h1>
                            <h2>Hello</h2>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Сделать заказ</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="img2">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="img3">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            ...
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-main" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-main" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>



            </div>
            <!-- /. Carousel -->
```

Comment: Please post your code here

Comment: `logo-meduim.png` is not resizing

Answer (score 0):

You should give Class to your Images like below :

```
<img **class="img-responsive"** src="img/show1.png" alt="" />
```

Css: img-responsive { max-width: 100%;}

Comment: Check this link: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178012/how-to-make-bootstrap-carousel-image-responsive

It will help you out

Answer (score 0):

you should give `width/height` directly to image like below :

```
<img width="as you define" height="as you define" src="img/show1.png" alt="" />
```